# Insert a XWPFParagraph in any position of a XWPFDocument

Tags: java, apache-poi

Do you know if is there a way to insert a paragraph (XWPFParagraph) inside a paragraph fullfilled document (XWPFDocument)?.

There is a method to "change" an already existing paragraph inside the document to another paragraph (XWPFDocument.setParagraph()) but I don't figure out how to insert NEW paragraphs into a specific position inside the document, not at the end with XWPFDocument.createParagraph().

Answer (score 10):

I've found a solution. The `XWPFDocument` has an ugly method `insertNewParagraph(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor)`. As you can see this method is passed a XmlCursor from the xmlbeans library. We can then do this:

```
XmlCursor cursor = par.getCTP().newCursor();
XWPFParagraph new_par = doc.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
new_par.createRun().setText("Stupid text");
```

Par is an XWPFParagraph inside the XWPFDocument doc. The new paragraph inserted (new_par in this snippet) will be inserted BEFORE the XmlObject the XmlCursor is pointing to.

Hope this help someone.

Comment: I tried this but the paragraph returned by `insertNewParagraph` is always null.

Comment: A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:,   while running your code. Still debugging, any Idea? no other information on why this error came

Comment: For those who get NULL by the 'insertNewParagraph' be sure that 'par' is taken from the 'doc'. insertNewParagraph will check if cursor belongs to the given document, if not returns null.

Answer (score 6):

I spent some hours wih this problem too. I had the the same problem as mentioned in the comment above. What worked for me was this:

After finding the right paragraph to do the insertion in `document.getParagraphsIterator()`, I had to use this code

```
XmlCursor cur = para.getCTP().newCursor();
cur.toNextSibling();
```

to be able to do `doc.insertNewParagraph(cur)`.

To my understanding my next fault was to try to insert several paragraphs at the position of the cursor. To make this work I had to add `cursor.toNextToken();` after the insertion.

Comment: Thanks! Did it for me... even in cell-context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`xwpfDoc.setParagraph(XWPFParagraph paragraph, int pos)`

to insert a paragraph at specific position

See the [link](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html) for details

Comment: This requires `xwpfDoc.createParagraph()` to be called or will throw an error

Comment: That is in question only